# "On mind" vs "in mind"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Are these interchangeable?

> - Do you have anything *in your mind*?
> - Do you have anything *on your mind*?

The first form seems to be the most commonly used one. But the second form is also used in some instances. And I am not sure if there is any difference at all. If both are correct, what is the difference?

Answer (score 24):

I don't think **in your mind** would be used as in your example. However we do say:

- Do you have anything *in mind*?

which means "What is it you are thinking of?" or "Do you have a preference/suggestion?"

> Want to go out for lunch?
>
> Sure. What do you have in mind?
>
> How about that new Thai place?

**in your mind** is used to mean "in your imagination".

> I swear, that guy is after me.
>
> Oh relax, it's just in your mind.

And **on your mind** indicates worry or preoccupation.

> You look worried. Do you have anything on your mind?

Comment: Thanks, but in The NY Times edition dated June 7th, 1878[link](http://query.nytimes.com/gst/abstract.html?res=F40610F83C5A137B93C5A9178DD85F4C8784F9)  it says: **Q.-Had you anything in your mind that his business was to work on you with...** Thoughts?

Comment: And why would Facebook say: What's on your mind? Does that mean worries... I don't think so.

Comment: @Mohammed Facebook's "What's on your mind?" means "What is preoccupying you".

Comment: Yes, "on your mind" is not always worry. But it is definitely about being preoccupied, which might mean you can't stop thinking about a good thing that happened, or are anticipating something in the future.

Comment: @Mohammad: The usage in the NYT quote seems to express the idea of "Did you ever imagine that..." or "Did it ever occur to you that...", which is close to the meaning of "in your imagination".

Comment: Having said the above, the Facebook prompt does seem a bit strange. In real life I don't think you'd ask someone "What's on your mind" unless it was apparent that the person was preoccupied or "lost in thought." But since the Facebook server can't see what you're doing when you log in, I suppose that's the best it can do.

Comment: Oh please! That NYT quote is from almost 140 years ago! We certainly don't normally use that phrasing today, and it might well have been atypical even then.

Answer (score 10):

When something or someone is **on** your mind, it means that you think and worry about this thing or person a lot.

When you have something or someone **in** your mind, you just think of this thing or person without the worrying connotation.

Comment: Facebook says: "What's on your mind". Does it mean that you are worried about something?

Comment: Upon reading this, the old country/pop ballad "Always On My Mind" popped into my mind.

Answer (score 6):

When speaking of, or asking about, what someone is thinking (or planning to do), overwhelmingly the most common wording is to ask what they [have in mind](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20in%20your%20mind,have%20on%20your%20mind,you%20have%20in%20mind&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) (never *have on mind*)...

[image]

I can't use a chart to show the difference between *have* **in your** *mind* and *have* **on your** *mind*, but normally the **in** version reflects the above *thinking, planning* sense. The **on** version is *only* used in respect of *obsessive, troubling* thoughts which are *preying on your mind*. Sometimes rather less extreme - not so much *oppressive* as *ever so slightly bothersome*. Just things which for some reason you're diffident about saying to other people.

OP's *Do you have anything in your mind?* would not normally be used in any context - except maybe facetiously, to mean something like *Do you not have any ability to think at all?* The second version would be normal phrasing if you had reason to suspect something might be bothering the other person, but weren't  sure. If you *knew* something was wrong you'd ask *What's on your mind?*

Answer (score 1):

The difference may not be sharp clear. Considering in and on, "mind" can be used in these patterns: in mind, in or on  my/your/his mind.

"In your/my/his mind" may mostly imply activities including "memory", "recollection", "remembrance", "plan", "intention" e.t.c.

```
He spent the next hour going over the trial in his mind.
```

on your mind, on the other hand, may imply "busyness", "thinking a lot" e.t.c - which may mean "worry about" or " to have something to say" or something else as a "result"

```
I have a lot on my mind at the moment
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think in many cases they are interchangeable.

> How can I forget you when your always on my mind? ~ Unknown
>
> What's On Your Mind? ~ Facebook
>
> I just simply write as it moves me. I may be writing about a book or a movie or a person, places where I've been or something I've done. Or politics. It's going to what's on my mind at the moment. ~ Tina Brown.

I don't think any of the above quotes suggest that the person is thinking *and worrying* about the thing they have on their mind. Though, having something "on your mind" may *often* imply that you are worried about it, it doesn't apply in *all* cases.

Generally, **On my mind** , if used to just convey about your thoughts, can be replaced by **In my mind**.